# Compile Groovy file with ant task

Tags: java, ant, groovy, javac

I don't understand why groovy.compile task runs when I'm trying to run compile task.

```
<taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="groovy.compile">
    <groovyc srcdir="src/groovytest" destdir="bin/classes"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" description="Compile *.java file" depends="init, groovy.compile">
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin/classes" debug="on" deprecation="true">
        <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Is there a way to compile .groovy with javac ant task and not groovyc ant task?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you need to use the `groovyc` task, however, you should be able to use the joint compiler by doing:

```
<taskdef name="groovyc" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc">
    <classpath>
        <path refid="compile.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="compile" description="Compile both groovy and java files" depends="init">
    <groovyc srcdir="src" destdir="bin/classes">
        <javac debug="on" deprecation="true"/>
    </groovyc>
</target>
```

Comment: Only gotcha I found was the need to include groovy-all-XX.jar in the classpath.  The embedded <javac> task inherits the classpath, srcdir and destdir from the <groovyc> parent.